# How to traverse folders in :edit command dropdown menu

Tags: neovim, edit

When opening a new file I use

```
:e <tab>
```

then a dropdown appears showing files in the PWD, I can move up and down with `<tab>` and `<shift>`+`<tab>`
Pressing `<enter>` accepts the selection and execute the command.

When I select a folder, I want to see the child files and keep navigating. However, if I press `<enter>` Ex

How can I accept the suggestion **without executing the command**?

[image]

Comment: what completion are you talking about? Can you please share a screenshot?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Added screenshot for clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<Right>` to enter a directory and `<Left>` to leave it.

Note that `:help 'wildoptions'` only lazily points to `:help ins-completion-menu`, which doesn't cover that special case anyway… so you are left with your intuition, here.

FWIW, I tried `<Right>` and `<Left>` because I am used to `<Down>` and `<Up>` in the wildmenu and the whole thing is turned 90°.

The documentation should be updated.

Comment: care to create a doc-pr?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I can, but not before this week-end.

Comment: no hurry, we have lived with that until now ‍♂️

Comment: In my case, `<up>` and `<down>` seem to do the trick.. maybe I have something messed up in my vim config?

Comment: okey, it seems that nvim has some problem with this, as stated in https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/9953

Comment: Well, nvim has something differently implemented. That's why, it usually helps to correctly state what product you are actually using

Comment: Other relevant docs: `:help 'wildchar'` --> `:help cmdline-completion`; `:help 'wildmenu'` (found with `:helpgrep <Right>`, but is the doc for this behavior). Which key to use depends heavily on wildmenu with or without "pum in wop": you need Down instead of Right when using the pum.

Comment: PS @ChristianBrabandt^

Comment: @D.BenKnoble  for me? what shall I do with that?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt thought you’d want to know it _is_ documented _somewhere_. Just belatedly realized that after posting the comment for Romain’s benefit.

Comment: yeah it is there, but perhaps we can add something for the `vertical` pum menu, which is quite new